# How do i invoke the onclick event in javascript? I don't want to use any events in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

How do i invoke the "onclick" event in Javascript? I don't want to use any events in my HTML page. The below code doesn't work.

HTML:

```
   <div id="myProgress">
       <div id="myBar">
        <div id="label">10%</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" id="blah">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
        }
    } 
} 


  document.getElementById("blah").addEventListener("click",move);
```

Comment: The way you add the event listener is correct. Are you sure you add it _after_ the DOM has been constructed?

Comment: You were right. I added it before the DOM was created. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your script at the end of body tag so that the DOM is loaded and your code works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, still doesn't work :/ When i do "onclick" in HTML it works, but doesn't work when i do addEventListener. Any solution?

Comment: Can you try including your script just before the end of body tag and check?

Comment: Yes, that works. It's just that my requirement says there shouldn't be any scripts in the HTML file.

Comment: Then where are you including your scripts ?

Comment: In a separate scripts.js file.

Comment: Include that script in <script src="scripts.js"> tag just before the end of body tag and it should work.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks man! Could you also explain why it wasn't working before and why it does now?

Comment: Awesome. You were probably including your scripts at the top even before the DOM is getting created. Including them at the end of body tag makes sure that the HTML is loaded. Please upvote my answer then. ;)

Comment: Oh. Alright! Got it. I would love to, but i have very less reputation and i'm not able to upvote your answer. Sorry Nihhilesh :)

Comment: Yes. Done! Also, is there any other way to do it with the <script> staying inside the <title> itself?

Comment: Thanks! You can wrap your javascript in window.onload function and try. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much. Here's the fiddle, doesn't seem to work :/ https://jsfiddle.net/ykx66zm3/

Comment: Umm. The fiddle is empty. Can you update the code there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the frame function outside the move function. And then call frame function from move function.

JS :

```
var width = 10;

function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
var id = setInterval(frame(), 10);


  } 

function frame() {
  window.width++; 
  elem.style.width = window.width + '%'; 
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = window.width * 1  + '%';
 } 


  document.getElementById("blah").addEventListener("click",move);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Add the other elements

```
<div id="myBar"></div>
<div id="label"></div>
```

2) And the CSS

```
#myBar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
}
```

3) Now, I prefer to work with `setTimeout` than `setInterval` as I find it handles better so I've rewritten the code slightly.

```
var bar = document.getElementById("myBar");
var label = document.getElementById("label");
var button = document.getElementById("blah");

button.addEventListener("click", frame, false);

var width = 0, timer;

function frame() {

  var loop = function (width) {

    // if width isn't specified set it to 0
    width = width || 0;

    // clear the timer if width is max
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    } else {

      // otherwise set the bar width and label
      var percent = width + '%';
      bar.style.width = percent;
      label.textContent = percent;

      // and call loop again, increasing the width by 1
      timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++width);
    }
  };

  // immediately call loop
  loop();

}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hx0oqsr1/12/)